# $this->db->group_by() and adding the quantity

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this in my receipt UI(Note: This is only from one user):

```
    Item_Name | Quantity | Price | Total
     Panty    |     2    |  50   |  100
      Bra     |     1    |  35   |   35
     Panty    |     2    |  50   |  100
```

As you can see the user gets the Panty TWICE!

I want my UI to be looking like this:

```
    Item_Name | Quantity | Price | Total
     Panty    |     4    |  50   |  100
      Bra     |     1    |  35   |   35
```

As you can see the Panty's that the user buys groups together, but in my query instead of Panty having 4 Quantity it still has 2

Here is my Code:

```
public function getClientReservation($name){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_item_availed');
    $this->db->join('tbl_items','tbl_items.Item_ID = tbl_item_availed.Item_ID');
    $this->db->join('user_account','user_account.Account_no = tbl_item_availed.Account_no');
    $this->db->where('Username',$name);
    $this->db->where('isReserve',1);
    $this->db->where('Active',1);
    $this->db->group_by('tbl_items.Item_Name');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Please help!

This is the table tbl_item_availed by the way:

```
   Item_availed_id | Item_ID | Quantity | Account_no
        1          |    1    |    2     |    5
        2          |    2    |    1     |    5
        3          |    1    |    2     |    5
```

table tbl_items:

```
   Item_ID | Price | Item_Name
       1   |  100  |  Panty
       2   |  35   |   Bra
```

table user_account:

```
   Account_no | Firstname | Lastname
       1      |  LeBron   |  James
       2      |  Dwyane   |   Wade
       3      |   Wilt    |  Chamberlain
       4      | Michael   |  Jordan
       5      | Charles   |  Barkley
```

Comment: maybe u have extra space in `Item_Name` column for Panty.

Comment: print the query and check

Comment: the thing is I can group_by() the Item_Name making it having one Panty alone BUT the quantities for both Panties are not merging, what query will I made? I think I miss something! a query i guess!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public function getClientReservation($name){
    $this->db->select('tbl_items.`Item_Name`, SUM(tbl_item_availed.`Quantity`) AS quantity, tbl_items.`Price`, (tbl_items.`Price`*(SUM(tbl_item_availed.`Quantity`))) AS total');
    $this->db->from('tbl_item_availed');
    $this->db->join('tbl_items','tbl_items.Item_ID = tbl_item_availed.Item_ID');
    $this->db->join('user_account','user_account.Account_no = tbl_item_availed.Account_no');
    $this->db->where('Username',$name);
    $this->db->where('isReserve',1);
    $this->db->where('Active',1);
    //$this->db->group_by('tbl_items.Item_Name');//do not use this line unless item name is unique
    //group by item id
    $this->db->group_by('tbl_items.Item_ID');


    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Also use `GROUP BY` for Item_ID (assuming it is unique), not Item_Name unless it is unique.

**Side note**:

Moreover, use `Account_no` instead of `username` in `WHERE` clause. If you want to modify it, just replace this line

```
$this->db->where('Username',$name);
```

with

```
$this->db->where('Account_no',$account_no);
```